# SharedPreferences not getting cleared android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, logout

I have a login functionality in my app. Here when the user logs in for the first time, The user details are saved in a shared preference file. When the user logs in the next time I the user is directed to the second screen directly. This works fine. Now I have implemented a logout functionality. Here I clear the preferences. Then if I login from another account I still get the user details of the first account.

Here is my code:-

```
   public class SessionManagement
{
     SharedPreferences pref;

        // Editor for Shared preferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        // ContextS
        Context _context;

        // Shared pref mode
        int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

        // Sharedpref file name
        private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";

        // All Shared Preferences Keys
        private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";

        // User name (make variable public to access from outside)
        public static final String KEY_EMAILID = "email";

        // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
        public static final String KEY_DEVICEURL = "deviceurl";

        public static final String KEY_ENDPOINTHOST = "endpointhost";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICENAME = "devicename";
        public static final String KEY_USERSNAME = "usersname";
        public static final String KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME = "encodedaccountname";
        public static final String KEY_HOSTURL = "hosturl";
        public static final String KEY_DEVICEiD = "deviceid";

        public static final String  KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED = "deviceregistered";
        // Constructor
         static SessionManagement session = null;

    public static SessionManagement  getInstance(Context context)
    {
    _context = context;
    if(session == null)
        session = new SessionManagement ();
    return session;
    }
    public SessionManagement()
    {

        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

        public void createLoginSession(String emailId, String deviceauthurl, String deviceid, String endpointhost, String devicename, String usersname, String encodedaccountname, String hosturl)
        {
            // Storing login value as TRUE
            editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

            editor.putBoolean(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED, true);
            editor.putString(KEY_EMAILID, emailId);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICEURL, deviceurl);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICEiD, deviceid);
            editor.putString(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, endpointhost);
            editor.putString(KEY_DEVICENAME,devicename);
            editor.putString(KEY_USERSNAME, usersname);
            editor.putString(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, encodedaccountname);
            editor.putString(KEY_HOSTURL, hosturl);

            // commit changes
            editor.commit();
        }

        /**
         * Get stored session data
         * */
        public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
        {
            HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

            user.put(KEY_EMAILID, pref.getString(KEY_EMAILID, null));
             user.put(KEY_DEVICEAUTHURL, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICEAUTHURL, null));
            user.put(KEY_DEVICEiD, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICEiD, null));
            user.put(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, pref.getString(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, null));
            user.put(KEY_DEVICENAME, pref.getString(KEY_DEVICENAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_USERSNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERSNAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, pref.getString(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, null));
            user.put(KEY_HOSTURL, pref.getString(KEY_HOSTURL, null));

            // return user
            return user;

        }
        /**
         * Check login method wil check user login status
         * If false it will redirect user to login page
         * Else won't do anything
         * */
        public void checkLogin()
        {
            // Check login status
            if(!this.isLoggedIn())
            {
                // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                  _context.startActivity(i);
            }

        }

       // This function clears all session data and redirect the user to LoginActivity
        /**
             * Clear session details
             * */
            public void logoutUser()
            {
                // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
                //editor.clear();
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEURL);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICENAME);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED);
                editor.remove(KEY_DEVICEiD);
                editor.remove(KEY_EMAILID);
                editor.remove(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME);
                editor.remove(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST);
                editor.remove(KEY_HOSTURL);
                editor.remove(KEY_USERSNAME);
                editor.remove(IS_LOGIN);
                editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();


                File file = new File("/data/data/com.zcv.acb/shared_prefs/UserDetails.xml");
                file.delete();


                // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
                // Closing all the Activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // Staring Login Activity
                _context.startActivity(i);

            }

            public boolean isLoggedIn()
            {
                return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
            }
}
```

Login.java

```
    SessionManagement sessionManager =SessionManagement.getInstance(this);
        session.logoutUser();
sessionManager.createLoginSession(username, deviceUrl, deviceId, endPointHost, deviceName, name, encodedAccountNameToken, hostUrlToken);
   if(sessionManager.isLoggedIn())
      {
          //Go directly to main activity
         HashMap<String, String> userDetails = sessionManager.getUserDetails();

        startMyActivity();
        finish();   
      }
```

Logout.java

```
SessionManagement session =SessionManagement.getInstance(this);
        session.logoutUser();
            this.finish();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

for save shared preferences

When **saving** shared preference call this way `savePreference("Username","some name");`

when **deleting** shared preference call this way `savePreference("Username","");`

```
private void savePreferences(String key, String value) 
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

for get shared preferences

now whenever checking the preferences when you get **empty String** redirect user to login Activity. else to user screen

```
private boolean loadSavedPreferences() 
{
    boolean check=false;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("Username", "");
    if(!name.equals(""))
    {
        check = true;
    }
    return check;
}
```

It's very simple.

**Update : 2**

```
public void createLoginSession(String emailId, String deviceauthurl, String deviceid, String endpointhost, String devicename, String usersname, String encodedaccountname, String hosturl)
    {
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        savePreferences(IS_LOGIN, true);

        savePreferences(KEY_DEVICEREGISTERED, true);
        savePreferences(KEY_EMAILID, emailId);
        savePreferences(KEY_DEVICEURL, deviceurl);
        savePreferences(KEY_DEVICEiD, deviceid);
        savePreferences(KEY_ENDPOINTHOST, endpointhost);
        savePreferences(KEY_DEVICENAME,devicename);
        savePreferences(KEY_USERSNAME, usersname);
        savePreferences(KEY_ENCODEDACCOUNTNAME, encodedaccountname);
        savePreferences(KEY_HOSTURL, hosturl);

    }
```

Keep One Thing in Mind . savePreference is only accept (String,String) you need to create one for (String,boolean)

Comment: the question is about deleting the shared preferences

Comment: how can i use the LoadsavedPreference() to logout then

Comment: when you load the preference and that time if you get all empty then you need to pass it to login.

Comment: Not working. When I hit logout button, the shared preferences file had a map with 0 elements. But later i still get the previous user detaikls

Comment: May be you r doing in wrong way , send me ur project on mail I'll correct it and give back to you

Answer (score 0):

```
    brother use this method to remove the string shared preference:

        public static void removeSharedPrefStringData(Context context, String key)
        {

            SharedPreferences appInstallInfoSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

            Editor appInstallInfoEditor = appInstallInfoSharedPref.edit();
            appInstallInfoEditor.remove(key);
            appInstallInfoEditor.commit();

        }

set and get preference methods are here:

    public static void setSharedPrefStringData(Context context, String key, String value)
    {
        SharedPreferences appInstallInfoSharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
        Editor appInstallInfoEditor = appInstallInfoSharedPref.edit();
        appInstallInfoEditor.putString(key, value);
        appInstallInfoEditor.commit();
    }

    public static String getSharedPrefStringData(Context context, String key)
    {

        SharedPreferences userAcountPreference = context.getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

        return userAcountPreference.getString(key, "");

    }
```

Comment: @raj what you want to ask??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are using 2 different objects of session management i.e Login has different object and logout has different object of session management. thats why it is not working . they both belong to different shared preference object. when you initialize logout object , one more shared preference object is created.The solution to this is either use singleton object or use static methods and members to solve your problem.But i guess singleton would be good for this . chnage your code like this :

```
public class SessionManagement {
static SessionManagement man = null;

public static SessionManagement  getInstance(){
if(man == null)
   man = new SessionManagement ();
return man;
}

...

}
```

and make your class constructor private(just remove public and replace with private in your constructor)

after this all code remain same.

now in login activity and logout activity , get your object by calling this

```
SessionManagement sess = SessionManagement.getInstance();
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but for sharedpreferneces i need a context. How do i use a context?

Comment: you can pass context as parameter in getInstance.